# 90th percentile accuracy in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have seen some 'odd' results in JMeter when it comes to calculating the 90th percentile response time from a test. I have a results.jtl from a one hour test, with approximately 20,000 data points per transaction. If I use the file to generate a dashboard with;

```
jmeter -g results.jtl -o c:\temp\report
```

I can see I get a 90th response time of 2261.10. If I look at the same results.jtl file through the aggregate report in JMeter (post test), I have 2260. I also used the percentile function in Excel which gave me 2260.3 (which ties in with the aggregate report). The 95th percentile is similar, I get 3551.50, 3549 and 3549.3 from each of the three calculations.

Has anyone else seen this type of discrepancy between reports? Is there anything I can do to correct the dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

The differences are due to approximation that is made by JMeter when computing the report.

This can be adjusted by increasing the value of this property:

> jmeter.reportgenerator.statistic_window=20000

See this [doc](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#reporting) and this blog:

- https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-achieve-better-accuracy-in-latency-percenti

By default JMeter tries not to consume too much memory.

Comment: I don't suppose you could recommend a value? As this is running on a decent sized box after a test I don't have to worry about it taking too much memory, I've added a couple of zero's (raised to 2000000) and it doesn't change the value.

Comment: Are you sure your change was taken into account ? check logs.How did you change it ?

Comment: I copied the line from reportgenerator.properties to user.properties and updated it to a larger value (removing the comment hash). But there is no mention of the value being set in the log, either set to the value I give it or set to a default value. Each time I run the report from the command line, making sure that there are no other Java processes left that may have done something 'odd' (like cache the properties file or look in a different location).

Comment: please double check as this has been confirmed at jmeter user mailing list who wrote the blog I added.